# How to display my value? using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

Hello can you please help me, my error is [object Object] I'm tired to fix this I want to display the result in the id="display" to show random number/value convert into second, minute, hour, day, month and year if you want to try in console he works but I want to display in p tag thank you for helping me :D

```
<p id="display"></p>
      

const SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE = 60;
const SECONDS_IN_HOUR = 60 * SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE; // 3600;
const SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY = 24 * SECONDS_IN_HOUR; // 86400;
const SECONDS_IN_ONE_MONTH = 30.439814814814813 * SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY; // 2630000
const SECONDS_IN_ONE_YEAR = 12 * SECONDS_IN_ONE_MONTH; // 31536000
function fromSeconds(value) {
    const seconds = Number.parseInt(String(value), 10);
    if (Number.isNaN(seconds)) {
        throw new TypeError('Invalid value to convert');
    }
    return {
        toMinutes: () => parseSecondsToMinutes(seconds),
        toHours: () => parseSecondsToHours(seconds),
        toDays: () => parseSecondsToDays(seconds),
        toMonths: () => parseSecondsToMonths(seconds),
        toYears: () => parseSecondsToYears(seconds),
    };
}

function parseSecondsToMinutes(s) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(s / SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);
    const seconds = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);
    return {
        minutes,
        seconds,
    };
}
function parseSecondsToHours(s) {
    const hours = Math.floor(s / SECONDS_IN_HOUR);
    const minutes = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_HOUR / SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);
    const seconds = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);
    return {
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds,
    };
}
function parseSecondsToDays(s) {
    const days = Math.floor(s / SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY);
    const hours = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY / SECONDS_IN_HOUR);
    const minutes = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_HOUR / SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);
    const seconds = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);
    return {
        days,
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds,
    };
}
function parseSecondsToMonths(s) {
    const months = Math.floor(s / SECONDS_IN_ONE_MONTH);
    const days = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_MONTH / SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY);
    const hours = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY / SECONDS_IN_HOUR);
    const minutes = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_HOUR / SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);
    const seconds = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);
    return {
        months,
        days,
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds,
    };
}
function parseSecondsToYears(s) {
    const years = Math.floor(s / SECONDS_IN_ONE_YEAR);
    const months = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_YEAR / SECONDS_IN_ONE_MONTH);
    const days = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_MONTH / SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY);
    const hours = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY / SECONDS_IN_HOUR);
    const minutes = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_HOUR / SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);
    const seconds = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);

    if (years === 0 && months === 0 && days === 0 && hours === 0 && minutes === 0) {
        return {
            seconds,
        };
    }
    else if (years === 0 && months === 0 && days === 0 && hours === 0) {
        return {
            minutes,
            seconds,
        };
    }
    else if (years === 0 && months === 0 && days === 0) {
        return {
            hours,
            minutes,
            seconds,
        };
    }
    else if (years === 0 && months === 0) {
        return {
            days,
            hours,
            minutes,
            seconds,
        };
    }
    else if (years === 0) {
        return {
            months,
            days,
            hours,
            minutes,
            seconds,
        };
    }
    else {
        return {
            years,
            months,
            days,
            hours,
            minutes,
            seconds,
        };
    }

}

//seconds
const result = fromSeconds(10000);

result.toMinutes();
// => { minutes: 525061, seconds: 1 }
result.toHours();
// => { hours: 8751, minutes: 1, seconds: 1 }
result.toDays();
// => { days: 364, hours: 15, minutes: 1, seconds: 1 }
result.toMonths();
// => { months: 11, days: 29, hours: 15, minutes: 1, seconds: 1 }
result.toYears();
// => { years: 0, months: 11, days: 29, hours: 15, minutes: 1, seconds:1 }


//console.log(result.toYears());

document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = result.toYears();
```

Comment: `result.toYears()` -> `JSON.stringify(result.toYears())`

Comment: the value is not showing

Comment: [Seems to work here](https://jsbin.com/jozupos/1/edit) using your code with only a single change of using `JSON.stringify()` in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to output an object, try parsing it into a string first, for example:

```js
const SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE = 60;
const SECONDS_IN_HOUR = 60 * SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE; // 3600;
const SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY = 24 * SECONDS_IN_HOUR; // 86400;
const SECONDS_IN_ONE_MONTH = 30.439814814814813 * SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY; // 2630000
const SECONDS_IN_ONE_YEAR = 12 * SECONDS_IN_ONE_MONTH; // 31536000
function fromSeconds(value) {
    const seconds = Number.parseInt(String(value), 10);
    if (Number.isNaN(seconds)) {
        throw new TypeError('Invalid value to convert');
    }
    return {
        toMinutes: () => parseSecondsToMinutes(seconds),
        toHours: () => parseSecondsToHours(seconds),
        toDays: () => parseSecondsToDays(seconds),
        toMonths: () => parseSecondsToMonths(seconds),
        toYears: () => parseSecondsToYears(seconds),
    };
}

function parseSecondsToMinutes(s) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(s / SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);
    const seconds = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);
    return {
        minutes,
        seconds,
    };
}
function parseSecondsToHours(s) {
    const hours = Math.floor(s / SECONDS_IN_HOUR);
    const minutes = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_HOUR / SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);
    const seconds = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);
    return {
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds,
    };
}
function parseSecondsToDays(s) {
    const days = Math.floor(s / SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY);
    const hours = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY / SECONDS_IN_HOUR);
    const minutes = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_HOUR / SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);
    const seconds = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);
    return {
        days,
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds,
    };
}
function parseSecondsToMonths(s) {
    const months = Math.floor(s / SECONDS_IN_ONE_MONTH);
    const days = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_MONTH / SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY);
    const hours = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY / SECONDS_IN_HOUR);
    const minutes = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_HOUR / SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);
    const seconds = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);
    return {
        months,
        days,
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds,
    };
}
function parseSecondsToYears(s) {
    const years = Math.floor(s / SECONDS_IN_ONE_YEAR);
    const months = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_YEAR / SECONDS_IN_ONE_MONTH);
    const days = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_MONTH / SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY);
    const hours = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_DAY / SECONDS_IN_HOUR);
    const minutes = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_HOUR / SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);
    const seconds = Math.floor(s % SECONDS_IN_ONE_MINUTE);

    if (years === 0 && months === 0 && days === 0 && hours === 0 && minutes === 0) {
        return {
            seconds,
        };
    }
    else if (years === 0 && months === 0 && days === 0 && hours === 0) {
        return {
            minutes,
            seconds,
        };
    }
    else if (years === 0 && months === 0 && days === 0) {
        return {
            hours,
            minutes,
            seconds,
        };
    }
    else if (years === 0 && months === 0) {
        return {
            days,
            hours,
            minutes,
            seconds,
        };
    }
    else if (years === 0) {
        return {
            months,
            days,
            hours,
            minutes,
            seconds,
        };
    }
    else {
        return {
            years,
            months,
            days,
            hours,
            minutes,
            seconds,
        };
    }

}

//seconds
const result = fromSeconds(10000);

result.toMinutes();
// => { minutes: 525061, seconds: 1 }
result.toHours();
// => { hours: 8751, minutes: 1, seconds: 1 }
result.toDays();
// => { days: 364, hours: 15, minutes: 1, seconds: 1 }
result.toMonths();
// => { months: 11, days: 29, hours: 15, minutes: 1, seconds: 1 }
result.toYears();
// => { years: 0, months: 11, days: 29, hours: 15, minutes: 1, seconds:1 }


//console.log(result.toYears());
//document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = result.toYears().hours + ":" + result.toYears().minutes + ":" + result.toYears().seconds;
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = `${result.toYears().hours || "00"}:${result.toYears().minutes || ""}:${result.toYears().seconds || "00"}`;
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: sorry, but if my value is 1 covert to 1 second, i want only show "second"

example your code results "undefinedyear undefinedmonths undefineddays undefinedhours undefinedminutes 1seconds"

Comment: for that situation you can either use template literals with a fallback value like this ````document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = `${result.toYears().hours || "00"}:${result.toYears().minutes || ""}:${result.toYears().seconds || "00"}`;```` or go with  VLAZ's suggestion by using `JSON.stringify(result.toYears());`